# Regular Expression - Select Line that ends with ";"

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code:

```
 if (Regex.IsMatch(fileLine, @"\s;$")) {
   listBox1.Items.Add(fileLine);
 }
```

I need to match a whole line ending with ";".

Comment: `fileLine` sounds like a single line so why not  `if (fileLine.EndsWith(";"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`string.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (fileLine.EndsWith(";"))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(fileLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Regex.IsMatch(fileLine, @".*;$"))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(fileLine);
            }
```

- `.*` will match anything

OR

shorter `@";$"`

Comment: You don't even need the `.*`. `Regex.IsMatch(fileLine, ";$")` suffices

Answer (score -1):

Probably this will solve `^[^;]*;$`